# Django populate choice from ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, foreign-keys

In the following code I am trying to have the Owner form with a drop-down menu that has car brands from the Car model as choices. I do get the drop-down menu but the elements listed as "Car object" each, instead of the brands. How do I get the brands from the Car model into the menu? Thanks.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Car(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Owner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    car_brand = models.ForeignKey(Car)
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, ModelChoiceField
from app.models import Owner

class OwnerForm(ModelForm):
    car_brand = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Car.objects.all())

class Meta():
    model = Owner
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `__unicode__` function to your model definition.

```
class Car(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.brand)
```

This way you can control what to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for sharing this, it helped me! In Django 1.8, try:
brand = models.ForeignKey(Car)

Dont put car_ in front of the foreign key